# Correct way of getting a currency value from a text field into a NSDecimalNumber

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I'm trying to optimise my code a little and I was looking at this part, where I save input prices into my `Core Data` entity, and I just feel like it's wrong/inefficient.

```
NSNumberFormatter *priceFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[priceFormatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
myEntity.price = (NSDecimalNumber *)[priceFormatter numberFromString:self.priceField.text];
```

Effectively what I think I'm doing here is creating an `NSNumberFormatter` which has a decimal style (obviously needed for prices, the text field may have an input of 2 instead of 2.00 so it is necessary to some degree) then using that `NSNumberFormatter` to put the value from the text field into the `NSDecimalNumber` via a cast. The reason why I want to get 2 into the form 2.00 is to save me from doing it when I load the entity and displaying it in the app. Also the text field regulates the text field so that it can't be more than 2 decimal places etc, so we don't have to worry about that bit.

Is this code efficient? Is there a better way of doing this? Is this even necessary?

Comment: hi try this NSLog(@"%.2f",[self.priceField.text floatValue]); will give u decimal point with two digit like price

Comment: @sugan.s Hmm interesting, so somwthing like this: `NSString *string = [NSString initWithFormat:@"%.2f",[self.priceField.text floatValue]];` and then do `myEntity.price = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberFromString:string];`?

Comment: yah try this hope will work fine @Mackey

Comment: @sugan.s Thank you very much. That definitely seems more efficient than the previous method.

Comment: k friend fine @MacKey can u tell me what is myEntity is this Model

Comment: It's a Core Data entity which I created. Price is an attribute of this entity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming this is a US Dollar only app, you can just use "cents" as your currency. This removes  a raft of problems that occur with floating point numbers. You would then have a simple conversion function or method that is used by ALL software displaying values - it divides the value by 100 to get dollars, then to get cents you subtract dollars*100 from the total and what left is cents, that you can easily display:

```
NSInteger total = ...;
NSInteger dollars = total/100;
NSUInteger cents = abs(total) - abs(dollars*100);
NSString stringWithFormat:@"%%d.%0u", dollars, cents);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Not only is it an app used all over the world, but in my opinion this over complicates things a little too much. On top of that, the server side code would have to be redone which would make it too much of a hassle to implement. Thanks for your thoughts though, it's always good to see another method.

Comment: I have an app in the store that did this. I would always be getting numbers back from the web using floating point - numbers like $13.29999999999 - it was hilarious. So I converted everything to cents when I first saw the value, and when I had to return numbers they were always strings containing the exact value (which if reconverted to floating point would again be crazy no doubt.) Seriously, you think this is a complex way to do it? I worked on another app where it was NOT done and we had all this code to do proper rounding. I found the above technique to be simple and 100% reliable. YMMV